# Extract numbers from html tags in R

Tags: r, string

I'm looking for efficient and elegant solution for numbers extraction from html tags such as

```
<spanclass=\"\">0.00</span>
-0.300</span>
-0,150</span>
<spanclass=\"\">-0,150</span>
```

so the desired output is supposed to be

```
  0.00
 -0.300
 -0,150
 -0,150
```

Thanks a lot for any of your advice in forward.

Comment: `-?\d+\.?\d+` is the regress you need. The second`?` is not necessary since it seems all your numbers do have a `.` in the case where that is absent then you will have to invoke `?` to capture that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How it should be implemented in e.g. gsub function?
gsub("-?\d+\.?\d+", "", '<spanclass=\"\">0.00</span>')) this doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at the rvest/xml2 packages.  They are designed to extract data from html.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(string,"-?\\d+\\S?\\d+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data (added fields for testing with commas):

```
string <- "<spanclass=\"\">0.00</span>-0.300</span>-0.150</span><spanclass=\"\">-0.150</span><spanclass=\"\">1,000.50</span>"
```

This captures the numbers with decimal points and signs (if they exist):

```
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches 
    (string,gregexpr("-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",string) )))
```

And this captures **both** decimal points and commas:

```
unlist(regmatches (string,gregexpr("-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*",string) ))
```

Comment: There are also values such as -0,300. Above solution won't work for these values.

Comment: So you have numbers with decimals *and* currency values with commas?

Comment: Yes, numbers with decimals and commas as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use RegEx or other string operations to parse HTML. Use `rvest` or another web scraping library.

```
require(rvest)

html <- "<spanclass=\"\">0.00</span>\n-0.300</span>\n-0,150</span>\n<spanclass=\"\">-0,150</span>"

h <- html %>% read_html() %>% html_text()

df <- data.frame(strsplit(h, "\n"))

names(df) <- "Values"

print(df)

  Values
1   0.00
2 -0.300
3 -0,150
4 -0,150
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract_all` from `stringr`package.

```
library(stringr)
Num.string <- str_extract_all(string, "-*\\d*[.|,]\\d*")[[1]] # captures numbers, either with "." or "," as decimal separator
Num.string <- sub("\\,", "\\.", Num.string) # replacing all "," by "."
as.numeric(Num.string) # setting all numbers to be numeric
[1]  0.00 -0.30 -0.15 -0.15
```

Using `%>%` from `magrittr` to avoid assignments

```
library(magrittr)
string %>%  str_extract_all("-*\\d*[.|,]\\d*") %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  sub("\\,", "\\.", .) %>% 
  as.numeric
[1]  0.00 -0.30 -0.15 -0.15
```