# Extract data from HTML tags in R

Tags: r, string, split, user-defined-functions

I have an html table I'm trying to extract data from. I have here line 21 that I need to achieve an 11 character vector from (and then do the same for all lines of data. I'm trying to write a function to do this, where:

`dt` is my data table and this is what line 21 looks like:

```
[1] "<tr><td>1</td><td>11 Com</td><td>b</td><td>Radial Velocity</td> 
<td>1</td><td>326.03</td><td>1.29</td><td></td><td>19.4</td><td></td> 
<td>2.7</td></tr>"
```

I need to get rid of all of the "`<tr><td>`" etc., as well as insert either a 0 or an NA where they exist back to back (`"</td><td></td><td>"`).

Here is what I have so far. First, I keep getting the error:

> Error in strsplit(a, `"</td><td>"`) : non-character argument

```
f<-function(row.data){
 a<-strsplit(row.data,"<tr><td>")
        b<-unlist(strsplit(a,"</td><td>")))
}
f(dt[21])
```

And this has yet to address inserting 0s or NAs. I'm quite new to R, so I am super appreciative of any help.

Comment: Couple things: you'd need to escape the slashes in your regex with an additional slash...this could easily get messy. There are also more appropriate methods of extracting data from HTML tags, such as using `rvest`, designed for this purpose. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49368027/5325862) with an `rvest` answer

Comment: Also, `rvest` includes a `html_table` function that wraps around several tasks needed to scrape data from a table. I'm guessing that since you've got `<tr>` tags, this is coming from a larger table in a web page? It might be easier to just start there with the entire table

Comment: Why aren't you using HTML parsers to work with HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `gsub`. As commented you should indeed escape the `/` with `\\`

```
dat <-  "<tr><td>1</td><td>11 Com</td><td>b</td><td>Radial Velocity</td><td>1</td><td>326.03</td><td>1.29</td><td></td><td>19.4</td><td></td><td>2.7</td></tr>"
a<-gsub("<tr>",0,dat)
a<-gsub("<td>",0,a) 
a<-gsub("<\\/td>",0,a) 
a<-gsub("<\\/tr>",0,a) 
a
[1] "0010011 Com00b00Radial Velocity0 \n0100326.03001.29000019.4000 \n02.700"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned above, your task is really parsing HTML, so a more appropriate method would be to use a package like `rvest` that's made for parsing HTML. I'm guessing this is part of a larger table, in which case you could probably use `rvest::html_table` to scrape data from an entire table at once.

If, instead, what you have is really just strings of the HTML tags for each row, you can convert that text to its XML representation (the backbone of HTML) with `read_html`. Then from that XML, you can pull out the `<tr>` tags, then from *those*, pull out the `<td>` tags. I did table rows before table cells in case there's more logic that you need for keeping rows together.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

tags <- "<tr><td>1</td><td>11 Com</td><td>b</td><td>Radial Velocity</td> 
<td>1</td><td>326.03</td><td>1.29</td><td></td><td>19.4</td><td></td> 
<td>2.7</td></tr>"

read_html(tags) %>%
  html_nodes("tr") %>%
  html_nodes("td")
#> {xml_nodeset (11)}
#>  [1] <td>1</td>\n
#>  [2] <td>11 Com</td>\n
#>  [3] <td>b</td>\n
#>  [4] <td>Radial Velocity</td>
#>  [5] <td>1</td>\n
#>  [6] <td>326.03</td>\n
#>  [7] <td>1.29</td>\n
#>  [8] <td></td>\n
#>  [9] <td>19.4</td>\n
#> [10] <td></td>
#> [11] <td>2.7</td>
```

Then `html_text` pulls the inner text out from each tag.

```r
read_html(tags) %>%
  html_nodes("tr") %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()
#>  [1] "1"               "11 Com"          "b"              
#>  [4] "Radial Velocity" "1"               "326.03"         
#>  [7] "1.29"            ""                "19.4"           
#> [10] ""                "2.7"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>